# time expression with from ... to vs between

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, usage

Which of these two expressions are correct?

1. I studied at school N4 **between** grades 1 and 4
2. I studied at school N4 **from** grades 1 to 4

Comment: Have a look at some of the answers here: https://www.google.com/search?q=from+to+or+between+and - there are even EL&U answers

Answer (score 1):

Between grades 1 and 4 refers to grades 2 and 3.
This indicated that you were studying somewhere else for grades 1 and 4 and you studied at school N4 for grades 2 and 3.

To study from grades 1 to 4 means you began at grade 1 and remained at that school for 2, 3, and grade 4.

Comment: It lends itself to that interpretation, yes, but it could also be interpreted as grades 1 through 4.